# How do you input CSS into an animate

Tags: jquery, css

I know about the JQuery:

`.animate()`

Though I was wondering how to incorporate css into it?

Any ideas?

Comment: This should help: http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.animate({//your css})`

Then it should work

Answer (score 1):

```
.animate({
    height: 100,
    width: 200,
    marginTop: 50
},duration)
```

Answer (score 0):

use
    .animate({any css you want to change})
, for ex

```
.animate({left:0px})...
```

this will animate the element to the left, you can also give a time for the transition to take place, like

```
.animate({left:0px},200)
```

where 200 specifies 200 mili seconds

Answer (score 0):

From documentation:

> `.animate( properties [, duration ] [, easing ] [, complete ] )`

**Description**: Perform a custom animation of a set of CSS properties.

```
$("#block").animate({width: "70%",}, 1500 );
Object with CSS properties ----^      ^--- Milliseconds
```

### Example

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
div {
background-color:#bca;
width:100px;
border:1px solid green;
}
</style>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <button id="go">&raquo; Run</button>

<div id="block">Hello!</div>
<script>

/* Using multiple unit types within one animation. */

$("#go").click(function(){
  $("#block").animate({
    width: "70%",
    opacity: 0.4,
    marginLeft: "0.6in",
    fontSize: "3em",
    borderWidth: "10px"
  }, 1500 );
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

More information on [documentation pages](http://api.jquery.com/animate/).